# Angular directive for route provider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

The [angular tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) invokes the `route provider` **explicitly** below, (being adapted for the sake of succinctness)

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/myResource1', 
        {templateUrl: 'partials/myView1.html', controller: MyController1}).
      when('/myResource2', 
        {templateUrl: 'partials/myView2.html', controller: MyController2}).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/index.html'});
  }]);
```

Can we define the `route provider` **separately**, then invoke it by means of `angular directive` below? Is there such a directive existing? Otherwise, how to make through with it?

```
function MyRouteProvider($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/myResource1', 
        {templateUrl: 'partials/myView1.html', controller: MyController1}).
      when('/myResource2', 
        {templateUrl: 'partials/myView2.html', controller: MyController2}).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/index.html'});
};
```

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js/MyControllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/MyRouteProvider.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-routeProvider="MyRouteProvider">

...

</body>
</html>
```

```
myApp
  |__index.html
  |__js
  |   |__MyControllers.js
  |   |__MyRouteProvider.js
  |__partials
      |__myView1.html
      |__myView2.html
```

Comment: ng-view is a directive which invokes routeprovider config ,why do you want to create your own directive?

Comment: What i wish to achieve is to remove the boilerplate invocation of `angular#module#config`. I'm unsure if it's feasible.

Comment: @sof You can define the routes within the module call: angular.module('myApp', [], ['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){...}]. I don't know why implementing an extra directive is needed.

Comment: My initial impression on `angularjs` is that the `route provider` could be made similarly to `ng-controller` with `code-behind` controllers but rather away from `injected services` with the aid of calling `angular#module`. Could be wrong or worthless.